# How can I define a variable as a dictionary in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that takes the contents of a text file and uses it as a dictionary.

When I put in this code;

```
A=open("dic.txt","r")
print(A.read())

if "A" in A:
    print("spam")
else:
    print("eggs")
```

I get this output:

```
{"A":1}
eggs
```

What I want is this:

```
{"A":1}
spam
```

Any ideas on how to do that? I don't understand why its not working.

These are the contents of the text file:

```
{"A":1}
```

Comment: please share the text file and what it looks like.

Comment: You can use `eval()` for this but its use is dangerous if the text file comes from unknown sources.

Comment: You need to save the content of a file to a variable. `print(A.read())` does not do that. Use `A = open("dic.txt", "r").read()` instead.
Also, when using `open()`, make sure you use `A.close()` at the end of your program for good practice.

Comment: I understand its case sensitive, but I tried after fixing it and it still did not work. I'm about to try Xay's suggestion.

Comment: It's not the solution to your problem, as the dictionary will still be a string when it's read from the file. Try some of the solutions below :)

Comment: Yep, I did, and I found a good one. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code currently:

1. You're never storing the contents of the file
2. You're never actually making a dictionary
3. The `read()` method of file objects returns a string, not a dictionary
4. You never closed the file

To fix this, you *can* use Python's built-in `eval` to parse the dictionary that is in a string, but this can be dangerous and unreliable.

Also, you can solve future problems like this by "spreading out" your code a little, meaning, make your code easier to read by having clear variable names and nice spacing so that debugging is easy to follow:

```
file       = open("dic.txt", "r")
contents   = file.read()
dictionary = eval(contents) # VERY dangerous

if "key" in A:
    print("key is in dictionary! :)")
else:
    print("key is not in dictionary! :(")

file.close()
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** Like some other posters on this thread, I also believe that `eval` should rarely be used, but in my opinion, it seemed like the easiest solution to this specific problem. I don't recommend using `eval` for other problems like this one unless you know *exactly* what you are doing. The other solutions using `literal_eval` and such may be better than this one (they were even posted before mine); I was just portraying a different solution that might have been interesting. Apologies to anyone who was misled and any Pythoners that were offended.

Comment: One should _almost never_ use `eval` for _almost anything_. A big downvote. Look at the alternative solution proposed by user3738870.

Comment: It did help! Thanks! That wasn't my best piece of work, so I'm glad it was just a test file. Thanks again!

Comment: @DYZ thanks for the feedback, edited my answer, hope this is better. If it is still a 'big downvote' please let me know and I will delete or further edit my answer :)

Comment: @AvivShai, to your EDIT: No one is offended, IMHO, but **"Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules."** See [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) or - alternatively - write `import this` to the Python interactive console.

Answer (score 3):

A working version could be:

```
from ast import literal_eval

A=open("dic.txt","r")

data = A.read()
print(data)

dictionary = literal_eval(data)
if "a" in dictionary or "A" in dictionary:
    print("spam")
else:
    print("eggs")
```

Comment: A little nicer: `for char in "aA": if char in dictionary: print("spam") break; else: print("eggs")`. - `for` and `else` have no indent, `if` is indented, first `print` and `break` are indented twice and the second `print` is (once) indented. - Yes, the `for` loop has an `else` branch, which is executed only if the break didn't perform.